# how to implement Infinite scrollview in android with loading message without using listview

Tags: android

I am inflating one XML which consists of text views and adding this XML view to my main layout.
My main layout having scroll view as a parent. Can any one tell me by using this data , how one can implement infinite scrolling showing loading message to footer.

Thanks a lot!! in advance..

Comment: You should describe what have you done and where is your problem. The answer for your question is very complicated and it would take probably hundreds of lines of code to solve it.

Comment: What i have done - > One.xml consisting of 3 textviews this xml inflated in view class(I have added these three textview in loop)  and this total view added in main layout. Now, this main layout in which i am adding this xml consisting scrollview as a parent so that it will look like a list. Now my question is how can i implement infinite scrolling using scrollview ?

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` is not good option here.

Here is how `ListView` works:

1. You have list of sth
2. You have adapter which creates `View` for each element
3. Android is destroying (or you may reuse it) unused `Views` and creating new one as the user scrolls
4. Your adapter should try to reuse old `Views`

In `ScrollView` you could do sth like that, but it will be very hard. The easier part:

1. You would need to detect that user scrolled to the bottom
2. Then you need to load new message and add it to the bottom of `ScrollView`

Then problems start appearing. As I said `ListView` is keeping only limited number of `Views` even for very big list. You need to implement sth like that for `ScrollView`.

Comment: Actually i havent use list view.. the req is not to use listview. please let me know what we can do for infinite sroll without using listview in android

Comment: @sog I did tell you what to do. You need to implement most of the `ListView` features by yourself. I won't implement it for you, because it would be huge piece of code and it will be bugged.

Answer (score 0):

*U CAN SO THIS BY SCROLL VIEW *

`TableLayout programaticTL = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.message_dynamic_table);
    TextView getdata_ = new TextView(Show_message.this);
    getdata_.setText("as u want ")
    programaticTL.addView(getdata_);`

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/myscrollview_message"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/header"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fillViewport="false"
        android:paddingRight="0dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="false"
        android:scrollbarSize="0dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="insideOverlay"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/message_dynamic_table"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </ScrollView>
  </RelativeLayout>
```